# Find certain value in dataframe

Tags: python

How to find certain value in dataframe?

example, I had a set a value {'Acc001', 'Acc001(1)', 'Acc002', 'Acc003', 'Acc003(1)'}.
Expect to display all the available value {'Acc001', 'Acc001(1)'} if search 'Acc001%'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL `LIKE` operator available in Pandas.

However, you can use Python's str functions, or even Regex.

---

> Expect to display all the available value {'Acc001', 'Acc001(1)'} if search 'Acc001%'.

```
df['some_col'].str.startswith('Acc001')
```

This is the equivalent code.